# What is the meaning of "on this one"?

Tags: meaning

Would you be so kind to explain the meaning of the phrase "on this one" please.

A little story:

A man had a lot of tasks in a school, but he didn't do them properly. He made a mess of them.

Another man said: "Follow me on this one."

In this context does "on this one" mean "Now (from now on) you should do it as I tell you", or does "on this one" = now?

Comment: **Follow me** on this one = **Pay attention to me and the way I do** this one. - "One" = this job/piece of work. (With the implication that the man should learn how to do the job from the other man.)

Comment: My guess based on very little information: the phrase means "on this matter." When we disagree, you may be right sometimes and I may be right sometimes. So as a general matter you would be wise to require proof rather my assurance alone. But "on this one," trust me although I cannot prove the point, because I'm sure of myself.

Comment: In this context, **on this** ***one*** is just the same as **on this**. It's *this* that's relevant. I'm assuming it's obvious from context; however, no context is provided in the dialogue in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"on this one" is synonymous with "in this matter (that we are considering)".

"You don't know the way through the maze? Follow me on this one."

"Making onion soup? Follow me on this one"